# Jquery: programmatically center elements

Tags: jquery, function, center, centering

I'm trying to create a function that I can apply to a div, and have that div **centered within it's parent, both vertically and horizontally**.

I'm trying to make the function of centering things generic so i don't have to keep rewriting the centering piece of code.

What would you do to make centering things easiest, WITH JQUERY.

```
$('p').hoverIntent(function () {
    var myObject = $('#bThis')
    var Ctop = $(this).offset().top + ($(this).height() / 2) - (myObject.outerHeight() / 2)     
    var Cleft = $(this).offset().left + ($(this).width() / 2) - (myObject.outerWidth() / 2)     

    if ($('#placeB').hasClass('place')) {    
        $(this).animate({color: "#999999", backgroundColor: "#f5f5f5"}, 400)
        $('#bThis').css({'left':Cleft, 'top':Ctop}).fadeIn(200)
    }

}, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({color: "#333", backgroundColor: "#fff"}, 200)
        $('#bThis').fadeOut(200)
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

See the working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/kE9xW/).

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="element">
        &nbsp;
    </div>
</div>

 <style>
  #container{
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background:#EEE;
    position:relative;
  }
  #element{
    height:50px;
    width:50px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background:#333;
    position:relative;
  }
<style>

<script>
  function centerDiv(element, xPosFromCenter, yPosFromCenter){

    var xPos = parseInt(element.parent().css('width'))/2 -parseInt(element.css('width'))/2 - xPosFromCenter;

    var yPos = parseInt(element.parent().css('height'))/2 -parseInt(element.css('height'))/2 - yPosFromCenter;


    element.css({top: yPos, left:xPos});
  }

  $().ready(function(){
    centerDiv($('#element'), 0, 0);        
  });
<script>
```

**End of Edit**

Well, wouldn't delegating the job of "center-ing" to its own function do the trick?

```
function centerDiv(element, parent){
  var Ctop = $(element).offset().top + ($(element).height() / 2) - (parent.outerHeight() / 2)
  var Cleft = $(element).offset().left + ($(element).width() / 2) - (parent.outerWidth() / 2) 

return {ctop: Ctop, cleft:Cleft};
}
```

In your calling function..

```
.
.
.
var obj = centerDiv($(this), $('#bThis'));
$('#bThis').css({'left':obj.cleft, 'top':obj.ctop}).fadeIn(200);
.
.
.
```

Comment: Excellent, that's what I was looking for. Haven't tried it but it looks like it'll work. Hey, if it's not too much trouble, how would I be able to add in an offset from the center? so if I want the element to be -100px up from the center of the parent, how would i make it so i could set that when i'm calling the function? so it's dynamic and i can customize it for every situation i need to? and is there a jquery tutorial/learning site that you would personally recommend, or no? thanks again man.

Comment: @nick: Might I suggest absolute positioning? While using absolute positioning within a div with relative positioning.. you can always specify `top:X px`. Where X = (ContainerDiv's Height/2) - 100

Comment: @nick:See my edit. passing 0, 0 would give you the exact center. As for jQuery tutorials there's tonnes of content out there on the web and it would be daunting to make any recommendations.. other than to say "Go out there and explore what suits your needs and what doesn't". :) Good luck!

Comment: Hey man thanks so much for the help, i edited your example: http://jsfiddle.net/kE9xW/1/ and was wondering if you knew how to fix it, basically if i have more than 1 container and element then it only applies to the first one. I know there's something you have to do in the end of the function to make it start again and look for the next.... i think... but i don't know what and i haven't found it so i thought i'd ask.

Comment: Firstly, you have duplicate id's..  http://jsfiddle.net/kE9xW/6/  As for, recursive centering..  hmmm..  You need to have a some 'pre-knowledge' of how your markup is gonna look like.. otherwise its like opening a can of worms..

Comment: HAAA, i laughed at someone who made the mistake of multiple ID's, and then i do it.... * embarrassing* but, I figured it out, woohoo: http://jsfiddle.net/kE9xW/7/   lol, or, you figured it out.